# TSQL Concatenate values from multiple columns into string in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I have a trouble which seems possible to solve but I don't have the right idea now.

I have a table with multiple columns with dates in column names. These names will be changing so I probably need a dynamic code. Here is how the table looks like:

```
ID  2014-01-01 2014-01-02 2014-01-03 2014-01-04 2014-01-05 2014-01-06 (...) 2014-12-31
1    1             0           1          0          0          0               1
2    1             1           1          1          1          1               1                                      
3    1             1           0          1          1          1               0
4    1             0           0          1          1          1               1
5    1             1           0          0          0          1               1
(...)
```

So, there is a sequence of dates with logical values `0` or `1`. What I need is to add another column to this set with a sequence of these values as a string like for example (for the ID = 1):

> 101000(...)1

As I mentioned, the dates can change.

Could you help me in that case ?

Comment: To summarize - you need code that concatenates row data into a single colum (for different number of  columns and with different names)?

Comment: This smells a little bit like an XY problem. If you don't mind, what are you planning to do with that string once you've got it?

Comment: Does it is actual table structure or result of `PIVOT`?

Comment: I agree with @lc. This seems like a bad design for a table. I would suggest changing to a table of dates, a table of ids, and a table for values (allowing many to many relationship between dates and ids.

Comment: I suppose he need some kind of export?

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov   Yes

Comment: Ok, but is this one table or many tables? Or new colums are added to the exitsing table? I have the same case - I have function which rturns propper string (although it is more complicated than 1 and 0, but the table structure is fixed). Add more details in question.

Comment: @lc.                                                                                                              That string will be used as an information about sequence of dates. "1" means that an event occured on that date, "0" that didn't occure. That specific format of data is required by another system that I am using

Comment: @lad2025                                                                                                    it is actual table structure

Comment: If you ask me, that sounds like a job for the next layer up, not SQL Server. And I agree with @ZoharPeled about the table structure. You want (Id, Date, EventOccurred). Then you don't need anything dynamic, nor a 365-column table just to store one year. In fact you don't even need the EventOccurred column; existence of a row means a "1".

Comment: @ZoharPeled                                                                                               I don't have any influence on the structure of this data, I need to manage with data like in provided sample

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov                                                                                                     It is one table, but in future the dates may possibly change. Of course I could just write a query in sql server, adding column such as ([2014-01-01]+[2014-01-02]+....+[2014-12-31]) but I want it to be more elastic in case of changing date sets.

Comment: You should change the table structure to make the date a field, then use a PIVOT or equivalent.

Comment: I think the best way is to have calculated field base on current table structure. It can change after structure of the table is chaged. Even the change of the structure is automatic the update of the calculated field can be managed by a DDL trigger. Of course you have to specify which is the version of SQL Server which you are using now.

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov       I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: So you can use DDL trigger (although I am not sure for certain that they can change tabale structure - you have to check). You can try to read current structure and compose calculated field expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you'll need dynamic SQL for that:

```
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
   DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(128) = 'FUNKTIONEN'

   SET @sql = (
   SELECT 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),ISNULL('+ name + ','''')) + '
   FROM sys.all_columns
   WHERE object_id = (
       SELECT object_id
       FROM sys.all_objects
       WHERE object_id = object_id(@tablename)
       ) FOR     XML PATH (''))

   SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 ' + LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql)-1) + 'FROM ' + @tablename

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```